# Setting up user.properties in jmeter for several load test

Tags: settings, jmeter-5.0

I'm setting up a load test for several threads that each one needs a specific token.

How can I outsource it via csv file or other solution?

Screenshot of code: [image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! Instead of posting an image of your code, type the code itself and format it in a code block. It will make it easier for other people to help you! Also, if you can, show examples of what you have tried :)

Comment: i had an issue to put the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a csv data set config in jmeter for csv/txt files. Keep data in external csv or text file and use in your jmeter script using csv data set config for your desired threads.

Make sure the number or records in the file should be the same as the number of threads you want to execute.

https://octoperf.com/blog/2018/01/25/jmeter-csv-data-set-config/